# C# split string with 1 or more whitespaces or on new line

Tags: split

I'm reading with StreamReader a sequence of numbers separated by 1 or more space and sometimes a new line occurs and there is no a space between 2 numbers:
"0.00 1.00 2.00 3.00 4.00 5.00 6.00 7.00 8.00 9.00 10.00 11.00
12.00 13.00 14.00 15.00 16.00 17.00 18.00 19.00 20.00 21.00 22.00
23.00 24.00 25.00 26.00 27.00 28.00 29.00 30.00 31.00 32.00 33.00"

I've tried to Split it with:
line.Split(' ','\n')
or
with Regex
string[] numbers = Regex.Split(line, @" +|\n");
but it doesn't work correctly, splits only when a space occurs but not when on new line.
Is there a solution for that?

Comment: Did you try `\s+`

Comment: Thanks for the response. This I didn't try. I've solved it with an another way and now works quite good. Anyway I left the old cold so be curious I will try to use also this.Thanks